# Excel Variable & Fixed Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a variable data in A and fixed data in B, now i want the data to be arranged in C as C1 will be the 1st variable data in A, and C2 will be the fixed data in B. C3 will be the 2nd variable data in A, and C4 will be the fixed data in B and so on.

There are 1000 no of such data so manually copy pasting is not a solution. Is there any other alternative way to do it very short.?

Comment: could you edit with a model of what you're wanting? i.e. a table with the initial state and a table with the desired state?

Comment: Is there a reason you're SHOUTING? It's clear your Shift key works properly from your text. Posting your question in ALL CAPS will not get you an answer faster, it's harder to read, and quite frankly it's somewhat rude and annoying. Please don't do so. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following formula into C1 and copy it down:

```
=INDIRECT("R"&INT((1+ROW(A1))/2)&"C"&2-MOD(ROW(A1),2),FALSE)
```

**EDIT for explanation**

INDIRECT function returns the value of a cell referred to in R1C1 format.

The INT((1+ROW(A1))/2) as the row counter and 2-MOD(ROW(A1),2) as the column counter will return the following:

```
Row1 - R1C1 (ie A1)
Row2 - R1C2 (ie B1)
Row3 - R2C1 (ie A2)
Row4 - R2C2 (ie B2)
Row5 - R3C1 (ie A3)
etc
```